# How to correctly type custom "Throttle" function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I have a function named "throttlePromise". It allows to limit the execution number of an asynchronous function in an interval and to automatically restart the last call at the end of the interval if it was prevented. This behavior is different from throttle implementations you might find online. With this implementation, intermediate calls are simply ignored.

```
export function throttlePromise<T>(
  fn: (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>,
  ms: number
) {
  let queuedFnCall = false;
  let queuedFnCallThis: any = null;
  let queuedFnCallArgs: any[] = [];
  let runningPromise: Promise<any> | null = null;

  function invokeFn(fnThis: any, fnArgs: any[]) {
    if (runningPromise === null) {
      runningPromise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
        const fnPromise = fn.apply(fnThis, fnArgs);

        Promise.allSettled([wait(ms), fnPromise]).then((results) => {
          runningPromise = null;

          if (queuedFnCall) {
            queuedFnCall = false;
            invokeFn(queuedFnCallThis, queuedFnCallArgs)
              .then(resolve)
              .catch(reject);
          } else if (results[1].status === 'fulfilled') {
            resolve(results[1].value);
          } else {
            reject(results[1].reason);
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      queuedFnCall = true;
      queuedFnCallThis = fnThis;
      queuedFnCallArgs = fnArgs;
    }

    return runningPromise;
  }

  return function (...args: any[]) {
    return invokeFn(this, args);
  };
}

function wait(ms: number) {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

I try to correctly type this function in typescript with less as possible "any" keyword.

Comment: What's the problem with your current implementation? Pasting it into the TypeScript Playground, I see an error with calling `invokeFn(this, args);` but nothing else. Is that the only issue you're looking to resolve, or are there others as well?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wEpEyW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.